# How can I show that this function is mesurable?

Tags: lebesgue-integral, measurable-functions

I want to show that the following function $$f:[0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}; (x,y)\mapsto y\sin(xy)$$ is measurable.

We had a theorem that says that for all $c\in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}([c,\infty))$ has to be in the sigma algebra of the domain. In our case I would assume that this is $\mathfrak{B}([0,2\pi]^2)$ where $\mathfrak{B}$ denotes the borel sigma algebra. But then if I consider $f^{-1}([c,\infty))=\{(x,y): y\sin(xy)\in [c,\infty)\}$ I don't know how to conclude. So i would say that if

1. $c>\max_{(x,y)}{f(x,y)}$ then $f^{-1}([c,\infty))=\emptyset\in \mathfrak{B}([0,2\pi]^2) $
2. if $c<\min_{(x,y)}{f(x,y)}$ then $f^{-1}([c,\infty))=\emptyset\in \mathfrak{B}([0,2\pi]^2) $
3. if $\min_{(x,y)}{f(x,y)}\leq c\leq \max_{(x,y)}{f(x,y)}$ then $f^{-1}([c,\infty))$ is an interval and a subset of $[0,2\pi]$ and thus clearly in $\mathfrak{B}([0,2\pi]^2) $

But does this argumentation works?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you know the theorem that continuous functions are (Borel-)measurable?

Comment: So I know that $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is mesurable if it is increasing. and that for a continuous function $g:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ it holds that $B$ is a borel set impies that $g^{-1}(B)$ is a borel set. But in this example we have non of the two cases.

Comment: Or can we see $[0,2\pi]\times [0,2\pi]$ to be homeomorphic to $[0,2\pi]^2$ and thus the second remark holds so we have the case of $g$ from above but with $[0,2\pi]^2$ instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: composition and product of measurable functions is measurable

Comment: @Masacroso ah so we can consider $g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}; g(y)=y$ which is continuous and thus from my remark from above also mesurable. Then also $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}; f(z)=sin(z)$ is continuous and thus from the same remark mesurable. Then $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}; h(x)=x$ is the same case as $g$. Now with mutliplication and composition we get what we want right? But does it matter that we dont have always $\mathbb{R}$ in our domain?

Comment: @Wave the general rule is that composition of measurable functions is measurable, and it hold for any kind of measurable spaces, try to prove it (the proof is trivial and one-liner)

Comment: @Masacroso yes sure but as I wrote above, when we for example want to multilpy $h(x)\cdot g(y)$ then it is mesurable if $h,g$ are mesurable. But we only know that if $h,g:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and continuous, that the are masurable. But in our example we would have $h,g:[0,2/pi]\rightarrow [0,2/pi]$ is it then still true?

Comment: @Wave it depend on the $\sigma $-algebra of the space to see if a function is measurable. If the $\sigma $-algebra of a topological space is the Borel $\sigma $-algebra then any continuous function between spaces with Borel $\sigma $-algebra will be measurable

Comment: ah okei but they can have different borel sigma algebras right? so if I have a continuous $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\mathfrak{B}([a,b])$ and $\mathfrak{B(\mathbb{R})}$ then it is mesurable automatically although we don't have the same borel sigma algebras

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mean a continuous function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R^m$ with possibly different $n$ and $m$? Because this is also true and then you could apply that to your function (with a little argument about why it also holds for functions defined on subspaces of $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: so we only proofed the case with $m=n$.

Comment: but as discussed above we could break the function down to cases with $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and then use that composition and multiplication respects mesurability right? Then the only part is that we here have a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ in the domain

Comment: Sorry but If I have two topological spaces $\Omega_1, \Omega_2$ endowed with the $\sigma$-algebra of the borel sets. And we have a continuous function $f:\Omega_1 \rightarrow \Omega_2$. Then this function is always mesurable. Since we know that the preimage of an open set under a continuous function is open and since open sets generates all borel algebras we are done right? And therefore we doesn't care if we have $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a domain or only a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ right?